# Push segues can only be used when managed by UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

This is a well known error but I'm only getting this through Crashlytics. I cannot at all reproduce this online.

If I trace through the paths in my Storyboards, everything seems to be fine and embedded in a UINavigationController (the default and most common answer).

Anybody an idea how to go about debugging this? Crashlytics won't show a real path to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got mine reproduced:

- In some cases a segue would be triggered after network request completion (I know…).
- While waiting for the network to complete, you could do all kind of weird things to the navigation stack.
- The network completes and tries to perform the original segue
- Crash.

The solution is this:

```
if (self.navigationController) {
  [self
    performSegueWithIdentifier:"mySegue"
    sender:self];
}
```

Posted here for future reference and maybe helpful to other developers.